# Тип сказуемого в предложении (1)

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые

Скажите, пожалуйста, в данном предложении сказуемым будет просто слово "продолжит" или сочетание "продолжит песенку" представляет собой описательный глагольно-именной оборот?

*Соловей продолжит песенку.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Соловей продолжит песенку.*

Продолжит песенку - не оборот, это свободное сочетание.

В словаре Ушакова

> продолжить, продолжу, продолжишь, совер.
>   1. (несовер. продолжать) что. **Продлить,** удлинить, увеличить, сделать большим, чем предполагалось. *Продолжить занятия до июля. Продолжить
>   отпуск. Продолжить дорогу до леса.*
>
> 2. совер. к продолжать в 1 знач.

https://znachenie-slova.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Как видим, продолжить - это продлить занятие чем-то ( после остановки в том числе). Можно продолжить песню, можно продолжить разговор,игру и т.д. Второй компонент **песенку** тоже свободно сочетается с другими глаголами - начал песенку, закончил песенку.

Сказуемое **продолжит** - простое глагольное. **Песенку** - прямое дополнение

Comment: @ Людмила, а вот интересно: соловей продолжил петь. Здесь ведь уже СГС?

Comment: Да, это составное глагольное сказуемое, и глагол продолжит имеет здесь вспомогательный характер, обозначает фазу ( продолжение) действия, но в "продолжил песню" глагол самодостаточный со своим собственным значением. Вот, например, прекратил петь - СГС (перестал петь), а прекратил песню - ПГС = оборвал песню, остановил песню, хотя в него входит и значение "прекратил петь песню", В любом случае "песню" в сказуемое не входит. А если "продолжил мелодию"? Здесь "продолжил" - точно  ПГС?

Comment: А есть разница между мелодией и песней?

Comment: Людмила, я с вами согласен. Просто интересно, значение одно и то же, а сказуемые разные.